# How to configure redshift XADatasource in WildFly 16

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, amazon-redshift

I am migrating an Spring Enterprise Java Application from Tomcat 6 to Wildfly 16, but I have not been able to configure an Amazon Redshift connection datasource . I am getting this message:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "redshift")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0114: Failed to load datasource class: com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.DataSource"
```

Also, at the end of the deployment, I get this message:

```
ERROR org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation  - WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("xa-data-source" => "jdbc/redshift")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.redshift",
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.redshift"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/resources/jdbc/redshift is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.redshift]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source.jdbc/redshift is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.redshift]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source.jdbc/redshift is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.redshift]"
    ]
}
```

My standalone.xml configuration is this:

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/resources/jdbc/myJndi" pool-name="jdbc/myJndi">
  <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">
    SomeIp
  </xa-datasource-property>
  <xa-datasource-property name="PortNumber">
    1634
  </xa-datasource-property>
  <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">
    myDatabase
  </xa-datasource-property>
  <driver>redshift</driver>
  <security>
    <user-name>user</user-name>
    <password>password</password>
  </security>
</xa-datasource>
```

Also in the standalone, in drivers section I have this:

```
<driver name="redshift" module="com.amazon.redshift">
  <xa-datasource-class>com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.DataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

If I configure this datasource with the `<datasource>` tag and `<connection-url>` , It does not show the error, but I am not able to use transactions.

NOTE: I found that Amazon Redshift is based in Postgresql, so I tried to configure this XADataSource with the same parameters but by using the postgresql driver, and it works apparently well (I use the XA Datasource Class `org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource`). I'd like to know if there is a way to solve this redshift problem without doing that (using postgresql driver). Is there anything wrong in my configuration? Which XADatasource class should I use for redshift?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are referring to the jdbc driver in your standalone drivers section, but the error shows that it is not installed. You can download the jdbc 4.2 compatible driver [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html).

Comment: the driver is already inside the `modules` folder, and the `module.xml` is referring to the redshift jar correctly, but it doesnt work. I also downloaded postgresql and I configured it in the same way as I did with redshift, and it works, What I've noticed, is that inside that jdbc driver from redshift, I can't find a class which implements XADatasource interface